# jQuery .animate() wont accept variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use an variable inside the jQuery `animate()` but it isn't working. I don't want to use the same code twice so is there a way to do this better?

The code:

```
var direction = 'scrollTop';
// var direction = 'scrollLeft';

var value = 2000;// changes everytime

$('html, body').animate({direction: value}, 1000, function(){
    // more code here
});
```

Comment: what is `direction: 2000` supposed to do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use:

```
var direction = 'scrollTop';
// var direction = 'scrollLeft';

var value = 2000;// changes everytime

var opts = {};
opts[direction] = value;

$('html, body').animate(opts,1000,function(){
    // more code here
});
```

Comment: Please be less wasteful of variable names. (`var opts = {direction: 2000}`)

Comment: @Cerbrus `direction` is a variable

Comment: I think you mean `var opts = { scrollTop: value }` @Cerbrus. Side note: I have no idea why that variable would be named `direction`.

Comment: Oh, the fact that `direction` is a variable is the reason OP's code is breaking, even. In his code, JS is using `"direction"` as the key, instead of the value of `direction`. Example: `console.log({direction: value}, opts);`